# broken responsive layout only on chrome and safari but firefox works

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

The site is on `http://4am-lesson.com/`.

My layout will be broken

The reproduce step is that

1. Narrow the width from full-width to half-width
2. The nav links layout will be broken when restore to full-width from half-width.

I wonder some information how to debug the kind of error.

The bug is most likely from `css` or `javascript` ?

Thanks very much

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: try commenting this css `nav.main {
/* float: left; */
}` from style.css

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes Thanks~ you solved the problem, but could you tell how to track this kind of bug ? or why ? Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try commenting this CSS

```
nav.main { 
    /* float: left; */ 
}
```

Inspecting it using `web-inspector` or `firebug` is best to track this kind of bugs